# making a trapezoid tab shape

Tags: css

I'm trying to replicate [this menu feel](http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/flat-tabbed-menu#) but I've some trouble making the trapezoid shape of the different tabs. I went through the source code and also in the dev tool I removed each css propriety one by one but still I'm not figuring it out. I also tried

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/activee/q6ur8dmm/1/) trying to replicate it (there is no trapezoid shape at the moment).

```
<nav>
        <ul>
           <li class=" active"><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">FORUM</a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>TRUC</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>OTHERS</span></a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>


nav{
    background:white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #50bfff;
}
nav ul{
    margin:0;
}
nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
nav a{
    padding: 1rem;
    color:#505050;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
nav ul .active{
    background:#50bfff;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the Trapezoid shape in the Source.
It is a perspective transformation, have a look at this fiddle.

```css
div{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: lightblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks, the annoying bit is that the text inside is transformed too.

Comment: Massively late but I thought I would add this for completeness: you can untransform the text literally by applying the opposite transform to it. The only bug being, it looks slightly iffy in Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```css
ul > li > a:hover{
    background:#50bfff;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    color: white;
}

ul > li > a{
    text-align:center;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 120%;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
}

nav{
    background:white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #50bfff;
}
nav ul{
    margin:0;
}
nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
nav a{
    padding: 1rem;
    color:#505050;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class=" active"><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">FORUM</a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><span>TRUC</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><span>OTHERS</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: That's not really related to my question ?

Comment: Yeah I just added my question :)

Comment: I understood at first in your question that you try to archive this hover effect, but now it should be ok.

Comment: Yeah it's like the answer above, the text is transformed too. I think it has to do with :after but I'm not sure. I'm investigating now.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some great instructions for shaping elements:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

The one you're looking for looks like this:

```
#trapezoid 
{ border-bottom: 100px solid red; border-left: 50px solid transparent; border-right: 50px solid transparent; height: 0; width: 100px; }
```